# Angular4 add WMS (openlayers)

Tags: angular, openlayers, geoserver, wms

I want to add an example **wms-layer** with OpenLayers from a GeoServer to my map in Angular 4 | 2.
I don't know the right syntax to do this.
Perhaps someone has some experience with OpenLayers in Angular2 or Angular4?
Thanks a lot!

**map.component.ts**

```
import {Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, ViewEncapsulation, Input} 

from '@angular/core';
import { WmslayerService} from '../../wmslayer.service';


import * as ol from 'openlayers';

@Component({
  selector: 'olmap',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  templateUrl: './map.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./map.component.css']
})export class MapComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  @Input() id3: number;

  mapId2: string;

  map: ol.Map = undefined;

  mapexample: ol.Map = undefined;


  constructor(private wmslayerService: WmslayerService) {

    // generate random id for every map
    this.mapId2 = "map" + Math.random().toString(36).replace(/[^a-z]+/g, '').substr(0, 5);

  }


  ngOnInit() {
    // test service
    console.log(this.wmslayerService.addMyWms());
    console.log(this.wmslayerService.layer);
    //

    console.log(this.mapId2);
  }

  // render the basic map
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.map = new ol.Map({
      target: this.mapId2,
      layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
          source: new ol.source.OSM()
        })
      ],
      view: new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([37.41, 8.82]),
        zoom: 8
      })
    });
    //

    //// add WMS layer to the basic map
    this.mapexample = new ol.layer.Tile({
      extent: [-13884991, 2870341, -7455066, 6338219],
      source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
        url: 'http://osgis.astun.co.uk/geoserver/gwc/service/wms?',
        params: {
          'LAYERS': 'osgb:district_borough_unitary_region',
          'VERSION': '1.1.1',
          'FORMAT': 'image/png',
          'TILED': true
        },
        serverType: 'geoserver'
      })
    });
    map.addLayer(mapexample);
    ////
  }

}
```

**map.component.html**

```
  <div  id={{mapId2}} class="map">

  <div><app-menue></app-menue></div>
  </div>
```

Just for information:
The idea is to inject from a form, with a service, custom specified url's from a GeoServer to render several layers in the basic map.

Answer (score 4):

I solved the answer, perhaps this could be helpful for someone else:

Adding a wms-layer additionally to a basic layer:

```
//// basic layer

var examplelayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
    url: 'https://ahocevar.com/geoserver/wms',
    params: {
      'LAYERS': 'topp:states',
      'TILED': true
    },
    projection: 'EPSG:4326',
    serverType: 'geoserver'
  })
});
this.mapId2 = "map";
this.map.addLayer(examplelayer);


////
```

And you have to quote the projection type in angular 4.
Params are optionally.